# Java HashMap - How to simultaneously get and then remove a random entry from a HashMap?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I was wondering if it is possible to get a random value from a HashMap and then straight after remove that key/value from the HashMap? I can't seem to find any method that works, would a different data structure be more appropriate for this?

Edit:
I should've been more clear, I generate a random number and then retrieve the value that corresponds with that random number. I need to return the value and then remove the entry from the map.

Comment: By simply calling the remove(key) that will remove the element with that key.

Comment: What do you mean by a **random** entry?  By whom will the random entry be chosen?

Comment: I should've been more clear, I generate a random number and then retrieve the value that corresponds with that random number. I need to return the value and then remove the entry from the map.

Comment: Use `.keySet` method on `HashMap` to obtain all the existing keys as a `Set`; use `.toArray` method on the key set to get an array of the keys.  Generate a random number between zero and the size of the key array; get the key `k` at that index, use `.remove(k)` on the `HashMap`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe `Map#computeIfPresent` would work in your case. From its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfPresent(K,java.util.function.BiFunction)):

> If the value for the specified key is present and non-null, attempts to compute a new mapping given the key and its current mapped value.
>
> If the remapping function returns null, the mapping is removed.

```
var map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

map.put(1, "One");
map.put(2, "Two");
map.put(3, "Three");

map.computeIfPresent(2, (k, v) -> {
    // `v` is equal to "Two"
    return null; // Returning `null` removes the entry from the map.
});

System.out.println(map);
```

The above code outputs the following:

```
{1=One, 3=Three}
```

If you were to use a `ConcurrentHashMap`, then this would be an atomic operation.

Comment: computeIfPresent returns new value, not the old one.

Comment: @KonstantinSvintsov Ok, what does that have to do with this answer?

Comment: I think it does not answer the question. The question is how to get value from map and remove that value with a single (atomic for synchronized map?) operation, computeIfPresent does not do that.

Comment: I agree with @KonstantinSvintsov

Answer (score 5):

The best way to both return and remove the key-value pair from a `HashMap` is by using the `remove(key)` method. This method removes the entry associated with the `key` and returns its corresponding value.

```
Integer randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(10);
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
String valueOfRandomNumberKey = map.remove(randomNumber);
```

Comment: can't get simpler than this :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
Hashmap<Integer, Object> example;
int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, example.size());
example.getValue() //do something
example.remove(new Integer(randomNum));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as I understand it, is this: given a `HashMap` you want to

1. Choose a key at random from among the the keys currently associated in the `Map`;
2. Remove that association of that randomly chosen key from the map; and
3. Return the value that had, until recently, been associated with that key

Here's an example of how to do this, along with some a little test/demonstration routine:

```
public class Main
{
    private static <K, V> V removeRandomEntry(Map<K, V> map){
        Set<K> keySet = map.keySet();
        List<K> keyList = new ArrayList<>(keySet);
        K keyToRemove = keyList.get((int)(Math.random()*keyList.size()));
        return map.remove(keyToRemove);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
            map.put("Key" + i, "Value"+i);
        int pass = 0;
        while (!map.isEmpty())
            System.out.println("Pass " + (++pass) + ": Removed: " + removeRandomEntry(map));
    }
}
```